# Unity3d always shuts down when launching on iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have a weird bug with my game on iOS platform.

When I build it from xCode it works great no matter how many times I run it. When I leave that build on iPhone 6s for one day it can't be opened anymore. When I click on icon it only shows black screen and then returns to home screen. If I double click menu button, the game is in active tasks and I can see that the game was loaded. But it cant be opened. Its like its always minimised or that graphics are failing.

I am using Unity 5.3.4f1 and graphic api is set to OpenGLES 2.0.

Has anyone else run to a problem like this?

Any suggestions or fix?

Edit:
So after testing it turns out it only happens with build from xCode and not with version that is on app store. So I guess it has something to do with provisioning profiles or similar.

Comment: When you leave it open running overnight or when you close it and try to re-open it the next day?

Comment: I close it or I leave it minimised. Never running all night

Comment: I met this problem too. device is ipad air 2, but it is not next day, it is about next week.

Comment: the multitasking menu does not show if an app is active. it is just a history of the last interacted apps and the image you see is not the current state, but just a screenshot from the last time it closed properly.

Comment: I don't know how to fix it. It happens in other version of unity too. The weird thing is that if I don't delete the app from device and just run it again from xcode it start working again.

Comment: in Xcode > Window > Devices > iPhone 6S > View Device Logs do you see crash logs? what type of provisioning profile are you using?

Comment: I cannot confirm that is happening with build that is already on app store. I'll have to wait till tomorrow to see what will happen. With developer provisioning(running from xCode) it definitely happens. I open'd crash logs and there is nothing from last 3 days so maybe it isn't crash or it cant catch it